# How do I read indented data?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a tab-separated file that looks like this:

```
ID  trait1  trait2  trait3
    1111    1   1   0
    2222    1   0   0
    3333    0   0   1
    4444    0   1   0
```

Notice the datalines are indented relative to the column headers.

I tried this syntax to read in the file and keep the column names:

```
df <- fread("/path/to/file", sep="\t", data.table=FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

The result looks like this:

```
df
  V1 1111 1 1 0
1 NA 2222 1 0 0
2 NA 3333 0 0 1
3 NA 4444 0 1 0
```

I've tried `strip.white = TRUE` but this didn't help.

Comment: You've got 4 columns in the header but 5 columns for the data; a typo?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Apologies, I corrected my mistake.

Comment: You could add `, drop = 1` if you don't mind the warning. There should be a GH issue regarding this, if not, [you could open one](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues)

Answer (score 1):

Both `fread` and `read.table` work; the additional whitespace (indentation) doesn't cause any issue.

**`fread`**

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("ID  trait1  trait2  trait3
1111    1   1   0
2222    1   0   0
3333    0   0   1
4444    0   1   0")
dt
#     ID trait1 trait2 trait3
#1: 1111      1      1      0
#2: 2222      1      0      0
#3: 3333      0      0      1
#4: 4444      0      1      0
```

**`read.table`**

```
df <- read.table(text =

    "ID  trait1  trait2  trait3
    1111    1   1   0
    2222    1   0   0
    3333    0   0   1
    4444    0   1   0", header = T)
df
#    ID trait1 trait2 trait3
#1 1111      1      1      0
#2 2222      1      0      0
#3 3333      0      0      1
#4 4444      0      1      0
```

Comment: I can replicate the problem with the text as: `"ID\ttrait1\ttrait2\ttrait3\n\t1111\t1\t1\t0\n\t2222\t1\t0\t0\n\t3333\t0\t0\t1\n\t4444\t0\t1\t0"`

Comment: @thelatemail `read.table` seems to have no issues with the string you give. Only `fread` complains.

Comment: Thank you for your help. `read.table` works for me but `fread` does not.

Comment: @TJ87 Yes I can confirm with thelatemail's sample string. TBH I'm not sure why. I found a [related (?) issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/529) which was closed years ago.

Answer (score 1):

`read_table2` from `readr` can also work

```r
readr::read_table2(
"ID  trait1  trait2  trait3
    1111    1   1   0
    2222    1   0   0
    3333    0   0   1
    4444    0   1   0
"
)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>      ID trait1 trait2 trait3
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1  1111      1      1      0
#> 2  2222      1      0      0
#> 3  3333      0      0      1
#> 4  4444      0      1      0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>